# Using ToListAsync() with Automapper ProjectToQueryable()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, automapper

I have a sync method which I'm trying to convert to async. Basically, the code below projects the data into a DTO, and selects rows and orders them based on properties of the DTO. It also gets only a certain 'page' of the data.

```
return GetDbContext().Items
            .ProjectToQueryable<DTO>(automapperConfigProvider)
            .Where({expression based on DTO})
            .OrderBy({expression based on DTO}).ThenBy(...)
            .Skip(skip)
            .Take(take)
            .ToList();
```

I tried to convert it like this but it fails on the `ToListAsync`.

```
var query = GetDbContext().Items
            .ProjectToQueryable<DTO>(automapperConfigProvider)
            .Where({expression based on DTO})
            .OrderBy({expression based on DTO}).ThenBy(...)
            .Skip(skip)
            .Take(take);
return await query.ToListAsync();
```

The exception I get is:

The source IQueryable doesn't implement IDbAsyncEnumerable. Only sources that implement IDbAsyncEnumerable can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations. For more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=287068.

I'm using EntityFramework, so the link in the exception does not make sense to me.

Has anyone encountered this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone reading this question, here is how I converted my method to async:

```
return await GetDbContext().Items
              .ProjectTo<DTO>(automapperConfigProvider)
              .Where()
              .Decompil‌​eAsync()
              .OrderBy().ThenBy(...)
              .Skip(skip).Take(take) 
              .ToListAsync();
```

Basically, I wanted the data server to do all the work in both projecting the dataset to DTO, and performing the query, and then picking only a subset of the result based on paging information.

I explored the `UseAsDataSource()` option which Jimmy Bogard mentioned in his comment to Darcy's answer. But I was using an AutoMapper `Profile` as a configuration provider for my mapping, and I could not quite figure out how to convert that to an `IMapper` to pass to `UseAsDataSource()`. So I ended up not doing as Jimmy suggested.

I'm sure there are other ways one could resolve this, but I did it through the code above.

Answer (score 1):

This because `ProjectToQueryable<T>`  does not implement `IDbAsyncEnumerable`.

However there is an async equivalent `.ProjectToListAsync<T>();` in the  [AutoMapper.EF6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper.EF6/) package.

Details here: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.EF6

Comment: `.ProjectToListAsync<T>()` would not meet what I want to do since it will load all data into memory before my `Where()`. It appears to be a problem on **DelegateDecompiler.EntityFramework** which **AutoMapper.EF6** uses. A similar issue was discussed [here](https://github.com/hazzik/DelegateDecompiler/issues/24). But the fix should be on the nuget package I've downloaded. Just not sure why it is still a problem, or if it is the same problem. Have not had a chance to have a look.

Comment: @FrankFajardo as a work around you may be able to put a `Where()` clause in before the `.ProjectToListAsync‌​<T>()`

Comment: I don't think so? I use the EF delegate decompiler package, which fixed the problem. But another option is the UseAsDataSource method, which translates the expressions back to the EF model so that EF processes the queries before projection.

Comment: @JimmyBogard, thanks for commenting. I was hoping you'd do that :) Which package has the UseAsDataSource method? I can't seem to find it. One thing I was thinking was do something like `queryable.ProjectTo<DTO>().Where<DTO>().DecompileAsync().ToListAsync()` I have not tried it, yet. Would that work?

Comment: @JimmyBogard, doing `queryable.ProjectTo<DTO>().Where<DTO>().Decompil‌​eAsync().ToListAsync‌​()` worked! It could perhaps be  Automapper.EF6's `ProjectToQueryableAsync()`? Happy to add it if you don't mind. :) Thanks for this valuable tool!

Comment: @JimmyBogard, I tried `UseAsDataSource()`. But I'm using a `Profile` as a `ConfigurationProvider`. I could not work out how to extract a `Mapper` object from my Profile to pass to UseAsDataSource(). Profile has GetMappers() but that returns `IEnumerable<IObjectMapper>`.